# I need simple unity ball bounce control to target position

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

Im in a unity project . I have ball object which is hitting or collide a uneven object with various speed. so the ball reflects in various angle.

but I need that ball to bounce to a target position.

Comment: Could you give additional information about your game and what you want to happen more specifically?

Comment: a ball is hitting a object but it reflect or bounce back to various angle . but i want the ball bounce to a target position

Comment: Do you have a script that is controlling this movement?